# How to not show ID in GridView but still get the value from client side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView right now that pretty much reflects a table in the database and I have selection enabled. So when the user hits 'Select' for a specific row, it looks in the first cell of that row, which is the ID of that entry in the table, then goes to my SQL table and gets that data and displays it on a different page. Is there a way I can do something similar without having to show the user the ID of each row?

Comment: You can make a link, or you can make a select with post back and read on post back the id (with out write it on grid). Show us some code to help you more.

Comment: [Here is the code behind](http://pastebin.com/W7sDJrD4) :: 

[And here's the aspx file](http://pastebin.com/UthZZh4t)

Comment: just put the element.Visible="false",element can be label,link,cell etc

Comment: I tried doing something like: Gridview1.Columns[0].Visible = false; But then when the user clicks "Select" and wants to view more information about that specific item, the way I pull information from the database is by using that ID in the column, but if I set the visibility to false, it no longer exists on client side, so I can't pull that data. I'm asking if there's another way to do that...

Comment: please show the code.. pastebin link has expired...

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that by putting `Gridview1.Columns[0].Visible = false;` You won't be able to pull the data on the client side. What you want to do, is still have that column passed to the Client side, yet invisible to the user.

This can easily be adding the following CSS style to your aspx page:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .invisible
    {
       display:none;
    }
</style>
```

And setting the `CssStyle` to your column like this:

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="productID" .... ItemStyle-CssClass="invisible"/>
```